# How to call a js folder inside Django static folder from an html file inside its own folder

Tags: python, django

I have a question using django 3.2.10. I can't download my js file which is inside js folder, also inside static folder. Additionally, I have a folder called views where there are my html files, they are organized by webapp name. I am calling a js file (perbd.js) from perbd.html. This is the structure of my project.

[image]

This is the line in my perbd.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/perbd.js '%}" ></script>
```

And I have these lines in my Settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )
```

The point is that It doesn't work my js. I have the snapshot from the firework inspector:
[image]

The files which have %20 in the end, they are not working. I don't know what does it mean? Also I attach the image from the firefox console:
[image]

I'm thinking that it could be the folders organization because perbd.html is inside persona folder. I really appreciate all your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have included a space in your static tag (at the end of the path) that shouldn't be there

Comment: Its just a typo {% static 'js/perbd.js' %} .. no blank after js but a blank before %